# Moving options between selects using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to move an option from one select to another. This is what I have so far.

**selects.html**

```
 <select multiple id="select1" class="Multiple">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
</select>

<section id="botons" class="botons">
    <input type="button" id="bAdd" value=">>">
    <input type="button" id="bDel" value="<<">            
</section>

<select multiple id="select2" class="Multiple">
        <option> </option>
</select>
```

**ajax/js**

```
$(document).on("ready",function(){
    $("#bAdd").on("click", function(){
        var option=$("#select1 option:selected").value();
        $("#select2").add($('<option></option>').value(option));
        $("#select option:selected").remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: your first select box Id is `select1`.try appending it to `select2`. and also the function in jquery is `val()` not `value()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bAdd").on("click", function(){
        var option=$("#select1 option:selected").val();
        $("#select2").append('<option>'+option+'</option>');
        $("#select1 option:selected").remove();
});
 });//submit click
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <select multiple id="select1" class="Multiple">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
</select>

<section id="botons" class="botons">
    <input type="button" id="bAdd" value=">>">
    <input type="button" id="bDel" value="<<">            
</section>

<select multiple id="select2" class="Multiple">
        <option> </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
var option=$("#select option:selected").value();
```

You are referring to the select with an id of `select`, but in your HTML you have given it an id of `select1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text of the selected option as you didn't set value for them.

```
 $("#bAdd").on("click", function(){
            var option=$("#select1 option:selected").text();
            $("#select2").append($('<option>'+option+'</option>'));
            $("#select1 option:selected").remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [**.clone()**](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy the selected element:

```js
$("#bAdd").on("click", function() {
  var option = $("#select1 option:selected").clone();
  $("#select2").append(option);
  $("#select1 option:selected").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" class="Multiple" multiple>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
<section id="botons" class="botons">
  <input type="button" id="bAdd" value=">>" />
  <input type="button" id="bDel" value="<<" />
</section>
<select id="select2" class="Multiple" multiple>
</select>
```

**References:**

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)